# Подключение шрифта к сайту

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. не могу применить шрифт

```
<p style="src: url(meiryo.ttf);font-size:22pt;font-weight:bold;">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сам файл шрифта лежит в корне

Answer (score 4):

Ответ выше правильный, но я его хочу дополнить чуток на своем примере:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: OpenSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src:    local("Open Sans Light"),
            local('OpenSans-Light'),
            local('Open-Sans-Light'),
            url('/fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Light.ttf')  format('truetype');
    font-display: swap;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: OpenSans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src:    local("Open Sans"),
            local('OpenSans'),
            local('Open-Sans'),
            url('/fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype');
    font-display: swap;
}
```

То есть, называете шрифт:

```
font-family: OpenSans;
```

говорите, какой стиль шрифта подключаете (типа там обычный или курсив):

```
font-style: normal;
```

Далее добавляйте жирность шрифта, в основном для light это 300, regular 400, bold 700:

```
font-weight: 300;
```

Далее веселее, мы как бы спрашиваем, есть ли у пользователя такой шрифт вообще на компе, и если да грузим его, а не наш:

```
src:    local("Open Sans Light"),
        local('OpenSans-Light'),
        local('Open-Sans-Light'),
        url('/fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Light.ttf')  format('truetype');
```

Ну и последний тренд, насколько я знаю, пихаем:

```
font-display: swap;
```

Теперь ваш шрифт будет использоваться только после полной загрузки, не мешая отображению сайта до тех пор (то есть сначала пользователь увидит шрифт по умолчанию, и только затем, когда прогрузится ваш сайт, он увидит новый шрифт)

Comment: ок. так все заработало. но проблема в том что из за этого страница стала весить 8.5 мегабайт из-за шрифта. другого варианта уменьшить страницу нет?

Comment: @AndreyVladimirovich ну дак это нормально, ты его подгружаешь после полной загрузки страницы теперь, тебя не должны пугать эти 8мб)))

Answer (score 3):

Вы не правильно подключаете шрифт:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Output Sans;
  src: url(output-sans.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(output-sans.woff) format('woff');
}
```

После чего в коде используйте его как:

```
font-family: Output Sans;
```

Более глубоко этот вопрос расcматривается [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTQ9FpT3ayc).

Comment: в случае автора `url("meiryo.ttf") format("truetype");`

Comment: Вообще если совсем правильно делать то лучше воспользоваться `https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator` и сконвертировать шрифты в woff2 и woff. После чего подключить к сайту именно в этих форматах и в таком порядке. woff2 и woff разрабатыва специально для веб и поддерживаеться всеми актуальными браузерами, включая IE.

Comment: страница из за шрифта весит почти 9 мегабайт

Comment: Если шрифт 9мб. это означает что там есть символы кроме алфавита. Этим символы нужно удалить. Можно попробовать: `fontmin` если не поможет тогда нужно очищать в ручном режиме с помощью `fontforge`.

Comment: Посоветовали еще 1 интересный модуль на тему оптимизации шрифтов: `https://github.com/filamentgroup/glyphhanger` . Он анализирует переданные ему документы и вырезает неиспользуемые символы из шрифта.